# What is the default location of Info files?

Tags: info

I am looking for "An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp", by Bob Chassell.

I can find two Info files on my Spacemacs:

```
SPC SPC emacs-index-search
SPC SPC elisp-index-search
```

Does Spacemacs come with any other Info files?
How would I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From any info buffer, type <kbd>d</kbd> to return to the main directory.  You should see many manuals -- including `Emacs Lisp Intro`, which is the one you're looking for.  Alternatively, <kbd>g</kbd> `(eintr)` will take you to it directly.

`M-x info` or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> will land you on the directory node by default, if you weren't already reading something specific.

Answer (score 4):

Those are probably inside the emacs info path, check this link out for more details

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPath

But basically, emacs uses either an environment variable INFOPATH (you can check this one using `echo $INFOPATH` in the terminal) or, if the first isn't defined, a variable named `Info-default-directory-list` in emacs. You can check the latter typing it in any buffer and pressing C-x C-e with the cursor after it. The folder will show up in the small message box in the bottom of the emacs window.

Mine is `/usr/share/info`, but I'm not sure if this changes in other distros.

Comment: Found the book at /usr/share/info/eintr.info.gz.
To open an info file, use the usual info invocation with a prefix argument:  SPC u C-h i /usr/share/info/eintr.info.gz

Comment: Although this answers the original question exactly, I ended up using phil's answer.  And I can only accept one answer :-)